# Convert QString to Pointer of QString

Tags: c++, string, qt, pointers

As i am no C(++) expert i am stumped by some stubbornness of the compiler not wanting to convert a, in this case, QString to a QString*.
I have a function:

```
bool getNextMessage(int sId, QString *msg, QString *cmd)
```

I am using pointers here because i can not return more than one variable (spoiled Perl coder ;) ) in C and i want to use this in a while(getNextMessage(...)){...} style loop.
Inside that function there is some SQL foo and this:

```
 msg = QString("");
 cmd = QString("");
 return false;
```

All that the compiler produces from this is this:

```
 cannot convert 'QString' to 'QString*' in assignment
```

Could you dear folks please lift the mystery for me? Thanks. :)

EDIT:
Solution: Using references now thanks to the pointer to them from leemes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you typically use *references*, not *pointers*. For C++ newbies, it's hard to get what the difference is. A short explanation would be "references are safer pointers".

```
bool getNextMessage(int sId, QString &msg, QString &cmd)
```

This way, you can call the method without converting to pointers before and use the references with the same syntax as you work with normal variables, so your code for setting the content of the strings is fine.

If you want to stick to pointers -- or, to understand how to do it with pointers -- this is how you work with pointers:

```
*msg = QString("");
```

`*msg` dereferences `msg`, meaning that you are working with the object *behind* the pointer. For function calls, there is the `->` operator.

Calling

```
msg = new QString("");
```

would be syntactically correct too, but doesn't do what you expect it to do! This line means that you allocate a new QString object and get a pointer of this newly created object. Then, you assign this pointer to `msg`. This is fine for following code within the function. However, you changed `msg` itself (the pointer address) and not the memory where `msg` points to. This means, that the caller won't notice *anything* here. The caller works with the old pointer after the function call.

Comment: Out parameters of functions are actually one of the view cases where I find pointers preferable over references: Create the QString foo on the stack, then pass it via &foo - the & indicates that it's an out parameter. An example of this pattern is .e.g. QString::toInt( bool* ok), where the ok returns whether parsing the int succeeded.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I agree with you when the parameter is optional, like in the `QString::toInt` example. If it is mandatory however, we can't pass a "null reference". So the default value would be an instance which isn't used afterwards... At the end, it's a matter of taste, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the following.

```
*msg = QString("");
*cmd = QString("");
```

Make sure your pointers are initialized.

Comment: Are you sure about that syntax?

Comment: @acraig5075 As `msg` is a pointer, `*msg` is an object. Assigning stuff to `*msg` will change the content at the location `msg` points to, so this is fine.

Comment: Please explain, why this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well a `QString` is not a `QString*`. Perhaps you want to dereference the pointer and assign to the object it points to:

```
*msg = QString("");
```

Or I expect the following is equivalent:

```
*msg = "";
```